# Get Vuforia target Image rotation in degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I using this code

```
imageTarget.transform.eulerAngles
```

to get an angles of rotation relative to the camera, but it's values poorly correlate with real angles. Examples:

Horizontal

[image: horizontal]

Vertical

[image: vertical]

How can I get angles which can help me to calculate orientation of target image?

Comment: The problem with quaternions is that they have multiple representations in Euler! It is saver to use Vectors. Every Transform has its `up`, `forward` and `right` vector and you can calculate the angles between them using [Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html). in your case you could "normalize" the rotation around world Up and right vector -> assume that the camera looks always flat on the target since you are only interested in the angle between the targets right and the cameras right

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it